# SQL Compare grouped values

Tags: sql, oracle

If we have a table like:

```
col1 | col2
-----------
A    | 1
B    | 2
A    | 1
C    | 16
B    | 3
```

How it can be determined if the all rows for given value in col1 are the same?
For example, here whe have only '1's for A, but for B we have '2' and '3'.
Something like:

```
A   | true
B   | false
C   | true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select col1, case when count(distinct col2) = 1
                  then 'true'
                  else 'false'
             end as same_col2_results
from your_table
group by col1
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a preference for using `min()` and `max()` for this purpose, rather than `count(distinct)`:

```
select col1,
       (case when min(col2) = max(col2) then 'true' else 'false' end) as IsCol2Same
from table t
group by col1;
```

Then comes the issue of `NULL` values.  If you want to ignore them (so a column could actually have two values, `NULL` and another value), then the above is fine (as is `count(distinct)`).  If you want to treat `NULL` the same way as other values, then you need some additional tests:

```
select col1,
       (case when min(col2) is null then 'true'           -- All NULL
             when count(col2) <> count(*) then 'false'    -- Some NULL
             when min(col2) = max(col2) then 'true'       -- No NULLs and values the same
             else 'false'
        end) as IsCol2Same
from table t
group by col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct(t1.col1), case when t1.col2=t2.col2 then TRUE else FALSE end 
from table t1, table t2 where t1.col1=t2.col2
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because `DISTINCT` applies to the entire row, not just a single output column. The parenthesis is superfluous (and only serves to confuse).